# SFML mouse button released is spamming

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using SFML and C++ and I am getting an odd problem,

Here is my main game update method

```
while (renderService.Window.isOpen())
{
    //Poll events
    sf::Event event;
    while (renderService.Window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            renderService.Window.close();
        running = false;
    }

    MouseMovment(event);
    MouseClick(event);
    Update();
    Draw();
}
```

and here is my MouseClick method

```
void Game::MouseClick(sf::Event event)
{
sf::Vector2i position = sf::Mouse::getPosition(renderService.Window);

    if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left && event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
    {
        std::cout << "Mouse released" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

now here is the weird part, in my console sometimes my cout will be spammed like 10/20 times, but sometimes it will work perfectly, am I calling the event wrongly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, suppose that a `MouseButtonReleased` event is fired and your polling function grabs it (follows the numbers in the comments):

```
while (renderService.Window.isOpen()) // 4) The loop starts again
{
    //Poll events
    sf::Event event; 
    while (renderService.Window.pollEvent(event)) // 1) Grabs the event // 5) No more events
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) // 2) Nope, it's not this one
            renderService.Window.close();
        running = false;
    }

    MouseMovment(event);
    MouseClick(event); // 3) Yes, handle it // 6) Uses the unmodified event variable - undefined behavior
    Update();
    Draw();
}
```

you should rather do something like:

```
sf::Event event;

// while there are pending events...
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    // check the type of the event...
    switch (event.type)
    {
        // window closed
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            ...
            break;

        // mouse button released
        case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
        {
           if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
            ...
        } break;

        // we don't process other types of events
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> now here is the weird part, in my console sometimes my cout will be spammed like 10/20 times, but sometimes it will work perfectly, am I calling the event wrongly?

i had same issue and then i started looking into how event.type changes and i realized there is no event for nothing happening, so when you release your button and check if button was released, then event.type remains as sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased until one of the other 23 events occur

this is what is causing spam, when you release left button and do nothing then event.type does not change and remains as sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased

one way to fix this behaviour is to manually set event.type to one of the other 23 events that you are not using in your code after you detect sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased, example from one of my projects

```
if (events.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased) {
            std::cout << "should only fire once\n";
            events.type = sf::Event::Count;
}
```

Comment: Your solution will work correctly, but isn't a good practice to follow. If someone else modifies your code and doesn't know that you rely on `events.type` having a certain value, you're going to have a bad time. To avoid this, you should only look at the event right after `pollEvent` returns `true`.

Comment: @Joald ah, thank you!

i didn't consider checking after pollEvent returns true!